# Recording Screens From Multiple Perspectives With Voices and Computer Audio

Tags: audio, recording

Me and my friends are doing a video cast and we're recording our screens in addition to Skype audio. The problem is recording Skype separately from other system audio. This is so we can switch perspectives and have the audio come over correctly. We've tried both recording the call, but its kind of disorienting because the Skype audio is different from each of our audios. Our recording program doesn't let us record only one program's audio, so we're in a bit of a dilemma.

I haven't been able to figure out a solution to this, so I came here, because somebody is bound to know. Has anyone created a work around for this? I have an extra computer that I can use if there is a solution that involves that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could both record your individual screens and microphone inputs. In after effects (or another program of choice) you have the ability to separate the audio and visual so it is possible to change perspectives without affecting the audio. This would probably require a little manual adjustment of one of the audio layers given the lag of skype.

Good luck!